# Calculate total in XSLT over possibly missing elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I keep having problems finding a way to calculate the total when one field does not exist in one of the students.  I keep getting NaN when i sum the chargers. How would I sum the chargers when one of the charges only exist in one student. Only student 2 has activity chargers but the first one does not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="students.xslt"?>

<students>
  <student id="001234" type="grad">
    <lastname>Jones</lastname>
    <firstname>Alan</firstname>
    <gpa>3.51</gpa>
    <chargers>
      <tuition>1200</tuition>
      <parking>35.20</parking>
      <health>18.20</health>
    </chargers>
  </student>
  <student id="001887" type="undergrad">
  <lastname>Chong</lastname>
  <firstname>Susan</firstname>
  <gpa>2.51</gpa>
    <chargers>
      <tuition>1645</tuition>
      <activity>50.20</activity>
      <parking>35.20</parking>
      <health>22.50</health>
    </chargers>
  </student>
</students>
```

This is how  I'm trying to calculate the total. 
`<xsl:value-of select="sum(//chargers) "/>`
 What would be the best approach ?

Would a `xsl:if` test would be need it?

```
<xsl:template match="chargers">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <b>Chargers:</b>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tuition:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="tuition"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:if test="self::node()[activity]"> 
      <tr>
        <td>Activity:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="activity"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:if>
      <tr>
        <td>Parking:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="parking"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>health:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="health"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total Chargers:</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(//chargers) "/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem isn't that `activity` may be missing but rather that you're selecting the `chargers` elements when you should be selecting the children of the `chargers` elements.

Change

```
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(//chargers) "/>
```

to

```
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(//chargers/*) "/>
```

to select the children of all of the `chargers` elements in the document.

The second problem is that you probably don't really want to sum across all `chargers` children across all `chargers` elements in the document.  Instead, you probably want to sum over the `charger` element children for the particular `chargers` element that you've matched.

If so, then change

```
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(//chargers/*) "/>
```

to

```
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(*) "/>
```

in your template that matches `chargers`.